# Sound wave animation page loader

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a sound wave looking page loader, but I can't make it disappear after the page loads.

```
.preload {
    z-index: 10001;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #121212;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.bar {
    background: #aa1515;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 3px;
    position: relative;
    width: 3px;      
    animation: sound 0ms -800ms linear infinite alternate;
}
 
@keyframes sound {
    0% {
        opacity: .35;
        height: 3px; 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;       
        height: 28px;        
    }
}

.bar:nth-child(1)  { left: 1px;  animation-duration: 474ms; }
.bar:nth-child(2)  { left: 5px;  animation-duration: 433ms; }
.bar:nth-child(3)  { left: 9px;  animation-duration: 407ms; }
.bar:nth-child(4)  { left: 13px; animation-duration: 458ms; }
.bar:nth-child(5)  { left: 17px; animation-duration: 400ms; }
.bar:nth-child(6)  { left: 21px; animation-duration: 427ms; }
.bar:nth-child(7)  { left: 25px; animation-duration: 441ms; }
.bar:nth-child(8)  { left: 29px; animation-duration: 419ms; }
.bar:nth-child(9)  { left: 33px; animation-duration: 487ms; }
.bar:nth-child(10) { left: 37px; animation-duration: 442ms; }​

.preload-finish {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const preload = document.querySelector('.preload');
    preload.classList.add('preload-finish');
});
```

It does appear first when something loads, but can't make it go away once the page has loaded.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the html part of it?

Comment: It's just a <div class="preload"> with 10x <div class="bar"> inside

Comment: have you tried `.preload-finish {  display: none;  }`

Comment: Yes and didn't fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an arguement (e) for this eventListener

```
  window.addEventListener('load',(event)=>{
   ...
   ...
  });
```

If you are still getting the error then it is because some files aren't loaded yet or not found.

Go to chrome dev tools and in console check whether any errors are being shown .

It could be a static file like images,css file etc ...

Also if there is any errors in your javascript then also then `load` event won't trigger

I tried your preloader for the demo

```js
window.addEventListener('load',(e)=>{
    $("#preloader").fadeOut();
  });
```

```css
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1999;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bar {
    background: #aa1515;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 3px;
    position: relative;
    width: 3px;      
    animation: sound 0ms -800ms linear infinite alternate;
}
 
@keyframes sound {
    0% {
        opacity: .35;
        height: 3px; 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;       
        height: 28px;        
    }
}

.bar:nth-child(1)  { left: 1px;  animation-duration: 474ms; }
.bar:nth-child(2)  { left: 5px;  animation-duration: 433ms; }
.bar:nth-child(3)  { left: 9px;  animation-duration: 407ms; }
.bar:nth-child(4)  { left: 13px; animation-duration: 458ms; }
.bar:nth-child(5)  { left: 17px; animation-duration: 400ms; }
.bar:nth-child(6)  { left: 21px; animation-duration: 427ms; }
.bar:nth-child(7)  { left: 25px; animation-duration: 441ms; }
.bar:nth-child(8)  { left: 29px; animation-duration: 419ms; }
.bar:nth-child(9)  { left: 33px; animation-duration: 487ms; }
.bar:nth-child(10) { left: 37px; animation-duration: 442ms; }​

.preload-finish {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<button>h4llo </button>
```

Comment: @dominus u can run the snippet & tell me what else u were looking?

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know the exact reason why this is actually happening, you're CSS definition for the individual bars seem to interfere with the switch of the it's parent container's `.preload` class to `.preload-finish`.

You can workaround by adding an empty class definition to your bars upon the switch to the `preloader-finish` class.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var preload = document.querySelector('.preload');
  preload.classList.add('preload-finish');
  var bars = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
  for (var a = bars.length - 1; a > 0; a--) {
    bars[a].classList.add('emptyBar');
  }

});
```

```css
.preload {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #121212;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bar {
  background: #aa1515;
  bottom: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  width: 3px;
  animation: sound 0ms -800ms linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes sound {
  0% {
    opacity: .35;
    height: 3px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 28px;
  }
}

.bar:nth-child(1) {
  left: 1px;
  animation-duration: 474ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(2) {
  left: 5px;
  animation-duration: 433ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(3) {
  left: 9px;
  animation-duration: 407ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(4) {
  left: 13px;
  animation-duration: 458ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(5) {
  left: 17px;
  animation-duration: 400ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(6) {
  left: 21px;
  animation-duration: 427ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(7) {
  left: 25px;
  animation-duration: 441ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(8) {
  left: 29px;
  animation-duration: 419ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(9) {
  left: 33px;
  animation-duration: 487ms;
}

.bar:nth-child(10) {
  left: 37px;
  animation-duration: 442ms;
}

​ .emptyBar {}

.preload-finish {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="preload">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<button style="position:absolute" id="clickMe">click me</button>
```